# Chances of raining over the weekend, chance of rain on saturday is 25% and chance of rain on sunday is 25%

Tags: probability

Right now I'm torn between using logic and using Bayer's thingy.

My logic tells me:

Change of rain on saturday : 25%

Chance of rain on sunday : 25%

Chance of rain on sunday and saturday 0.25²

Which gets me at around 56% chance of rain. Using Bayes would get me at around 60 i think

Is my thinking correct?

Comment: (0.25)^2 is 0.0625, i.e. 6,25%... It would be odd if the chances of having rain on both weekend days is higher than having rain in a single day, wouldn't it?

Comment: Are we to assume that rain on the two days is independent?  Doesn't seem likely.

Comment: It does not seem likely, but independence is probably assumed here, since this seems like an introduction to probability course question.

Comment: Bayes, not Bayer.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is not correct ... assuming you are asked to find the chance of it raining anytime over the weekend.

Assuming the event of it raining on Saturday is independent of it raining on Sunday (which is a pretty dubious assumption, but hey!), the chance of it raining over the weekend is the chance of it raining on Saturday *or* on Sunday ... which is 1 minus the chance of it not raining on both days, which is:

$$1-(0.75)^2=\frac{7}{16}$$

We can also use:

$$P(SaturdayRain \cup SundayRain) =$$

$$ P(SaturdayRain) + P(SundayRain) \color{red}{-} P(SaturdayRain \cap SundayRain) =$$

$$ 0.25 +0.25 - (0.25)^2 \approx 0.44$$

I think you tried to use this formula but *added* the probability of it raining on both days rather than *subtracting* it, thus ending up with about $56$%. But as pointed out in the comments, it of course makes no sense if the chance of either one happening are greater than the chances of either one happening individually added together.

Comment: Why is it a dubious assumption by the way? I just got this prognosis, that says there's 25% of it raining on sat and 25% chance of raining on sunday. What could it be dependent on?

Comment: If it rains one day, there would be less water in the clouds afterwards. But you don't have to worry about it for your problem since independence appears to be assumed.

Comment: @Nephilim The weather depends on lots of factors, but most likely some of the same factors making it rain or not rain one day are also factors making it rain or not rain the next day.

Comment: @Bram28 how would I change my events, if I were to use the Bayes theory? P(B) would be rains over the weekend, what would my first event be then?

Comment: @Nephilim Bayes' Law is used to figure out *conditional* probabilities. But in this auestion you are not asked about any confitional probability. Thta is, you are not given that some related event $A$ already happened in order to figure out the chance that $B$ happens. So, Bayes' Law is not applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

The compliment rule is the most simple approach here.

$$\begin{align*}
P(\text{rains this weekend})
&= 1-P(\text{does not rain this weekend}) \\\\
&= 1-\frac{3}{4}^2 \\\\
&= .4375
\end{align*}$$

Comment: If there is 30% chance of rain forecast for today, tomorrow, and the next day, does that mean there is `1-(0.7^3) = 66%` chance of of rain happening at least once during that time period?

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the event it rains on Saturday and $U$ be the event it rains on Sunday. If it rains over the weekend, it rains on Saturday or Sunday or both; let this be the event $E=A\cup U$.

The easiest way to calculate $\operatorname{P} (E)$ is $$\operatorname{P} (E) = 1-\operatorname{P} \!\left(E’\right) = 1-\operatorname{P}\!\left(A’\right)\!\,\operatorname{P} \!\left(U’\right)\!$$

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(\text{Rain})=1-P( \text{no rain}) =1-P((\text{ no rain on sat) and ( no rain on sun)} ) \\= 1-P( \text{no rain sat}) P ( \text{no rain sun}) =1- \frac{3}{4}\times \frac{3}{4} =\frac{7}{16}.
\end{eqnarray*}
So thats $43.75 \%$ chance of rain. You double counted it raining on both days.

Comment: If there is 30% chance of rain forecast for today, tomorrow, and the next day, does that mean there is `1-(0.7^3) = 66%` chance of of rain happening at least once during that time period?